# Meaning of "take" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: meaning, grammar, american-english

I couldn't understand the mechanism of a sentence from the  book ***Born to Run*** by Christopher McDougall:

> when it comes to grabbing a spotlight and persuading people to do
>   things they’d rather not, Fisher could put a televangelist to shame
>   (well, as much as that’s possible). Take this classic Fish tale that
>   Krakauer tells about a rafting trip Fisher made into the Copper
>   Canyons in the mid-1980s.

My problem is with the second sentence `Take this classic...`. I can't understand the usage of the verb "take" at the beginning and so the rest of the sentence confuses me.

Comment: "Take under consideration ..."

Comment: It means *You, reader, take...*

Comment: Just replace _Take_ with _Consider_ or _Consider, for instance_,

Comment: It's another way of saying "for example."

Answer (score 1):

It means

*You, reader, take this classic tale...*

which is an imperative or "command" or "suggestion."

The meaning of *take* here is that of *consider as an example*.

(See [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take) definition  18b.)

Answer (score 0):

Take in this context sets up an example of Fisher's persuasiveness. You could read it as "Take, for example, this classic Fish tale...."

Comment: thank you. and am I wrong about the idea that we need a comma after "take" at the original text?

Comment: @nadasaboori No, you don't need a comma. It's an imperative: *take this X*.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a partial sentence? "Take this classic Fish tale that Krakauer tells about a rafting trip Fisher made into the Copper Canyons in the mid-1980s" is a fragment that should probably be followed up by something like "which illustrates the principle of manipulation on the weak-minded"

Take is inviting the reader to take this example as if the author is 'giving' it to you as a gift. It's like a transactional prepositional phrase in this usage.

Comment: Not a fragment but an imperative. The subject (you) is understood.